# App works fine on later versions iOS 13 and so on but crash on iOS 12 with below crash

Tags: ios, swift

[Crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbfN0.png)
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named UINavigationBarAppearance because no class named UINavigationBarAppearance was found; the class needs to be defined in source code or linked in from a library (ensure the class is part of the correct target)'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

---

Comment: Can you show some of the code and error screenshots

Comment: @Larme it does not work

Answer (score 0):

UINavigationBarAppearance is only available from iOS 13.

Checkout the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbarappearance

You need to exclude the code using `UINavigationBarAppearance` for iOS version lower than iOS 13:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
  let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
  ...
  navigationBarAppearace.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
}
```

Comment: i have added the check in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions but it stills crash

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named UINavigationBarAppearance because no class named UINavigationBarAppearance was found; the class needs to be defined in source code or linked in from a library (ensure the class is part of the correct target)'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: I don't know what to do now ....I am still facing same crash even after applying check